# Elegant approach when generating html that depends on dynamic information

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, dynamic

I am a junior programmer working with Ruby on Rails. I am curious what is the best/elegant approach when you have to show content that has different states.

For example: I have a form on a page that can be shown, hidden (replaced with some text), or disabled (three states) - depending on users rights and other variables.

Is it best to put the form in a partial? Make different partial for different form states? Use helpers to wrap the logic?

Also, what's the best approach when I only have to add(or not to add) a class tag to a HTML element (decision made depending on some variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the show/hidden/view must be based on some business rule, so you should not implement that purely in the front-end. For instance, if you actually fetch the data but hide it using a style, the data is not really hidden. So it should be implemented in the middle tier "Controller" of your application.